# Selecting row using long variable (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim finishedStartRow As Long
Rows("finishedStartRow:finishedStartRow").Select
```

I'm trying to select the row 481805 using the finishedStartRow variable. I'm getting a type mismatch error because .Select can only handle Integers. Is there a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Try: `Rows(finishedStartRow).Select`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The dim'med var should not be included in quotes.

```
Dim startStartRow As Long
Dim finishedStartRow As Long

startStartRow = 2
finishedStartRow = 481805

'all of these are valid for variations on selection¹
Rows(finishedStartRow).Select
Rows(finishedStartRow & ":" & finishedStartRow).Select
Rows(startStartRow & ":" & finishedStartRow).Select
```

---

¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>